# Turn off viper-mode in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, viper-mode, vimpulse

This seems very simple, but I wonder how to turn off viper-mode once I turn it on with `M-x viper-mode`. I tried `(setq viper-mode nil)` but this did not do it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try <kbd>M-x</kbd>viper-go-away<kbd>RET</kbd>. Also <kbd>M-x</kbd>toggle-vipper-mode<kbd>RET</kbd> if you want to go back and forth.

Answer (score 6):

You can also switch back and forth between Viper mode and Emacs mode in a single buffer with ctl-z.